# Application data views in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Our application uses Cosmos DB to store data. The DB is partitioned based on User ID and all backend services work fine using the User ID.

However, we have a UI where only admins have access and they are different from the users stored in DB. They fetch data from DB based on time. That is, get reports from DB for last 3 days (doesn't matter what user ID). In this case, the query needs to fan out to all partitions. Moreover, stored procedures are scoped per partition and cannot be used in this scenario. Even though we are able to fetch data through query, it's a huge performance hit.

Can anybody please advise if there is a way in Cosmos DB to workaround this?

Comment: How much of a "performance hit"? How many partitions is your data using? Can the performance problems be solved with some targeted denormalization?

Comment: Sorry I was trying to mean "it will be a huge performance hit". Currently, it's a small set of test data. But in actual production, the number of requests per day will be in the order of 500,000. And that many docs will be created in DB. Considering that we feel it will be inefficient to query that way and it doesn't offer transactional support too.

Comment: Typically such cross user work is read only and doesn't call for ACID transactions. Also, it's less of a performance hit than you might imagine. It is an RU hit though. The fan out is done in parallel so there is very little hit to latency. I had a similar design and similar worries so I did some at scale experiments to get comfortable with the limitations. The system runs fine now with just a bit of targeted denormalization.

Comment: Our data is partitioned based on UserId and the user base is around 2 million. I am not sure how many partitons it will create. When two UI users query asking for first 20 records within last 3 days, then both users should get different results. That is, first users gets the first 20 and the second gets the next 20. And when the UI processes records, if some failure occurs, the reports should be left as is and picked in next iteration. In successful processing, the report properties will change. Hence we need transactions.